# MySQL match against sub select

Tags: mysql

I have a query on a full text column 'abstract':

```
SELECT title 
FROM citation 
WHERE MATCH(abstract) 
AGAINST ('+orange' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

My question: I want to generate the AGAINST clause using results from a sub select, eg (pseudocode):

```
SELECT title 
FROM citation 
WHERE MATCH(abstract) 
AGAINST ( 
 CONCAT("'","+",
  SELECT names
  FROM fruits
  WHERE type = "citrus"),"' "
), "IN BOOLEAN MODE"
)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The arguument in against needs to be a constant.
Take a look at this document here. [click to see](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match.)

Your query is much likely to work with `LIKE` however using this makes your query a lot slower.

Or you could do something like

`SET @finding_element=(SELECT c1.full_name FROM customer c1 WHERE c1.id=2); SELECT c.full_name FROM customer c WHERE MATCH(c.full_name) AGAINST((@finding_element));`
(query I have is used is just for reference)
Happy Learning